# Count of a occurrence of specific string in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
Auction_Date Auction_No   L1_Status   L2_Status  L3_Status 
2022-08-01   AUC00123     Acc         Rej        Acc
2022-08-01   AUC00122     Rej         Acc        Acc
2022-08-02   AUC00223     Acc         Acc        Acc
2022-08-12   AUC00221     Rej         Rej        Acc
```

Now I want to have another column where count of `L1_Status`, `L2_Status` and `L3_Status` would be shown when Status  = 'Acc'. So the resultant table would be like

```
Auction_Date Auction_No   L1_Status   L2_Status  L3_Status   Count_Acc
2022-08-01   AUC00123     Acc         Rej        Acc             2
2022-08-01   AUC00122     Rej         Acc        Acc             2
2022-08-02   AUC00223     Acc         Acc        Acc             3
2022-08-12   AUC00221     Rej         Rej        Acc             1
```

I know one approach could be `UNPIVOT` the last 3 fields and then get `Acc` count. Then this `UNPIVOT` table would have to be joined after `GROUP BY Auction_No` with above table to get the `Count_Acc` field.

Or

```
SELECT Auction_No, SUM(CASE WHEN L1_Status = 'Acc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                   SUM(CASE WHEN L2_Status = 'Acc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                   SUM(CASE WHEN L3_Status = 'Acc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Acc
FROM Table GROUP BY Auction_No
```

Is there any better approach?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't store denormalized data. Data of the same "type" ought to be stored in *one* column. You'd then have another column containing `1`s, `2`s and `3`s *as data* rather than mistakenly embedding that data into column names.

Comment: As an aside, if you do unpivot the columns you don't have to join back to get your desired output, you can do the pivot in a sub-select.  - [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88fdd1ad6175fa09f933b7e0c0013bde). Also your example above doesn't appear to need the aggregation to get the desired results. A simple case expression would do. An example of this is included in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is already good, but I have a shorter approach :)

```
SELECT Auction_No
    , SUM(IIF(L1_Status='Acc',1,0) + IIF(L1_Status='Acc',1,0) + IIF(L1_Status = 'Acc',1,0)) as Count_Acc                   
FROM Table GROUP BY Auction_No
```